# Wso2 scim/Users endpoint brings less attributes

Tags: api, wso2, scim, wso2-identity-server

Using the wso2/scim/Users endpoint as described in [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/SCIM+APIs) i am supposed to get a response like this one

```
     {  
   "schemas":[  
      "urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0"
   ],
   "totalResults":2,
   "Resources":[  
      {  
         "id":"0032fd29-55a9-4fb9-be82-b1c97c073f02",
         "userName":"hasinitg",
         "meta":{  
            "lastModified":"2016-01-26T16:46:53",
            "created":"2016-01-26T16:46:53",
            "location":"https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users/0032fd29-55a9-4fb9-be82-b1c97c073f02"
         }
      },
      {  
         "id":"b228b59d-db19-4064-b637-d33c31209fae",
         "userName":"pulasthim",
         "meta":{  
            "lastModified":"2016-01-26T17:00:33",
            "created":"2016-01-26T17:00:33",
            "location":"https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users/b228b59d-db19-4064-b637-d33c31209fae"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

But i need some extra info for every user and doing subsequent requests for every user using the id to get the extra information (like an email) is too bad.

Is it possible to configure the endpoint response so that i get the information needed for the users in one request ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with [SCIM extensions](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Extensible+SCIM+User+Schemas+With+WSO2+Identity+Server).

This [blog post](https://medium.com/@Dilshani/scim-extension-in-wso2-is-d30e8b0e8bc6) has more details.

Answer (score 0):

In WSO2 Identity server 5.3.0, you can achieve this by using the `attributes` query parameter.

eg. Following request will list all users along with their given names in a single call.

```
curl -k --user admin:admin 'https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users?attributes=givenname'
```

Please refer the post [here](https://medium.com/@pulasthi7/scim-list-users-with-given-attributes-in-wso2-identity-server-5-3-0-8360522d3ea9) for more details.

Comment: Yeah that worked!! When i was passing the attribute givenname... it was giving me the same response because it was already in the fields that would be send back. I was expecting only the givenname to be returned.
In the post you linked you say about having scim enabled for the user stores.I did enable scim but how do i query for all stores ?

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on your requirement. Are you expecting the response only to provide the attributes you ask to list? If it is so, it's not possible because username, scim id, created, modified all are compulsory meta attributes that should have in the response. Can you update your question with a sample response you are expecting if it is not what I mentioned here.

Comment: No worries its ok that i get this response and thank you for your answer.
How do i need to set my query so that a query for all the UserStores set up in Wso2? Because right now i am getting only results from primary user store and i want to get results from the other user stores as well